# Vb picture box (n)

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim x As String
    Dim zombies As List(Of Zombie)
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim boxes As List(Of PictureBox)

    x = diceRoll(4)
    RichTextBox2.Text &= "You rolled a " + x & vbCrLf
    RichTextBox1.Text &= "There are " + x + " Zombies attacking" & vbCrLf
    zombies = makeZombies(Val(x), 4)' x zom w/ 4 max health

    n = 0

    boxes.Add(PictureBox1)
    boxes.Add(PictureBox2)
    boxes.Add(PictureBox3)
    boxes.Add(PictureBox4)




    For i = 1 To Val(x)
        n = n + 1
        boxes(n).Image = My.Resources.zombie



    Next

    fight(zombies)
End Sub
```

I have 4 picture boxes, I am trying to get it so when a number is rolled on a dice ( diceroll(4) )  depending on what your rolled the image of the picture boxes will change. If a 3 is rolled 3 out of the 4 picture boxes will change to the picture, other wise they are clear pictureboxes. The image is in my resources called zombie.png.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: does `diceRoll()` return a string? That seems like an odd choice... but if not, why do you keep using `Val()`?

Comment: joel the diceroll is a function which just rolls a dice., val Is used to turn x into a value it would not work without it.

Comment: If you don't even know if it returns a String or an Integer, you need to find that out. You will continue to struggle as a programmer until you develop of sense for the **types** resulting from each variable, value, and expression you're dealing with in your code. This especially holds in a strongly-typed platform like .Net, but will even trip you up in dynamically typed platforms like javascript or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple problems. One is array/List indices start at 0 rather than 1, but the `n` variable increments to 1 before it is used as an index for the first time. Also, you don't initialize the `boxes` collection... it's a null reference/Nothing when you try to use it.

This code fixes those issues and does some other cleanup:

```
Dim x As Integer = diceRoll(4) 'If this function returns a string, fix it to use Integer instead
Dim zombies As List(Of Zombie) = makeZombies(x, 4)' x zom w/ 4 max health

Dim boxes As New List(Of PictureBox) From {PictureBox1, PictureBox2, PictureBox3, PictureBox4}
boxes = boxes.Take(x).ToList()

RichTextBox2.Text &= "You rolled a " + x.ToString() & vbCrLf
RichTextBox1.Text &= "There are " + x.ToString() + " Zombies attacking" & vbCrLf

For Each box As PictureBox in boxes
    box.Image = My.Resources.zombie
Next

fight(zombies)
```